# Given $f: A \to B$. Show that $f(f^{-1}(B_o)) \subset B_o$ and that equality holds if $f$ is surjective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $f: A \to B$. Let $A_o \subset A$ and $B_o \subset B$. Show that $f(f^{-1}(B_o)) \subset B_o$ and that equality holds if $f$ is surjective

**My Attempted Proof**

By Definition $f^{-1}(B_o) = \{b | f(b) \in B_o \}$. Put $b' \in f^{-1}(B_o)$, then $f(b') \in B_o$ and we have $f(f^{-1}(b_o)) \subset B_o$, which proves the first part.

Now assume we assume surjectivity of $f$, and we need to prove $B_o \subset f(f^{-1}(B_o))$

Take $\beta \in B_o$. Then we have again by the definition $f^{-1}(B_o) = \{b | f(b) \in B_o \}$. Put again $b' \in f^{-1}(B_o)$.

Now for every $b' \in f^{-1}(B_o)$, since $f$ is surjective we have $\beta = f(b')$, and thus $\beta \in B_o \implies \beta \in f(f^{-1}(b_o))$, therefore $B_o \subset f(f^{-1}(B_o))$ and thus equality follows. $\square$

---

Is my proof correct and logically sound/rigorous? Any comments on my proof-writing is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show $f(f^{-1}(B_0))\subset B_0$ and that equality holds if $f$ is surjective](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270169/show-ff-1b-0-subset-b-0-and-that-equality-holds-if-f-is-surjective)

Answer (score 3):

The first part of your proof is correct. In the second part, you are not interpreting surjectivity correctly. You have $\beta\in B_{0}$. Since $f$ is surjective, you know there is some $\beta_{0}\in A$ such that $f(\beta_{0})=\beta$. Thus, $\beta_{0}\in f^{-1}(B_{0})$, since $\beta\in B_{0}$. But then, $\beta=f(\beta_{0})\in f(f^{-1}(B_{0}))$, which proves that $B_{0}\subset f(f^{-1}(B_{0}))$.

Surjectivity guarantees that for every $b\in B$ there is an $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$. It does not imply that every element in $f^{-1}(B_{0})$ gets mapped to $\beta$ as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y\in B_0$, by definition of surjectivity there is $x \in f^{-1}(B_0)$ (i.e. that set is not empty) such that $y=f(x)$ which means that $y\in f(f^{-1}(B_0))$.

We showed that $\forall y\in B_0, y \in f(f^{-1}(B_0))$, i.e. $B_0 \subset f(f^{-1}(B_0))$. By double inclusion you have your equality.